# How does one show the revenue on y-axis instead of record count?

Tags: dashboard

I've tried all kinds of things, but basically, I want to create a line chart which shows revenue on y-axis and date on x-axis. This is what I have in my report but the dashboard shows record count in the y-axis, which is obviously not what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have grouped by date. In that case you need to tell salesforce how to group the revenues as well. So:

- go to the report editor
- hover over the revenues column header (so that a triangle appears at the right of the column header)
- click the triangle and select 'Summarize this field'
- you probably want to select 'sum' here, and click 'apply'
- click on 'add chart' (or 'edit chart' if you already have one)
- revenue will now be selectable as alternative for row count

Answer (score 1):

Go to the component editor for your dashboard component.  Click on the "Component Data" tab.  Select "Net Converted Amount" from the "Y-Axis" drop down list.  My screenshot below shows "Sum of Amount" but yours should show "Net Converted Amount".  Make sure you are summarizing the "Net Converted Amount" field on your report.

[image]

Comment: It only shows Auto and Record Count.

Comment: On your report, make sure you are summarizing your "Net Converted Amount" field.  Only fields that are summarized on the report will show up in that drop down list.